# Move test cases with complete data(test data,steps, etc) across team project collections

Tags: tfs, testcase, workitem, team-project-collection

I am looking a tool that can move the test cases around 100+ with entire data from one team project collection to other.

Along with the above one I need answer for below quesries:

1. Can we copy the DB tables with the test cases in it from source project collection to target one?
2. Can I download all of the Test Case data from the source Team Project Collection into a Spreadsheet and then upload the spreadshseet into the target team project collection?

Is there any tool that can support above mentioned scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [WI Migrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanMorgenstern.WIMigratorforVisualStudio2017) tool, it's a great tool (and free up to 250 work items).

> WI Migrator performs a migration of TFS work items environment from a
>   Team Project to another, cross TFS collections / servers. WI Migrator
>   duplicates the work items, restores the links between them, and
>   recreates the test plans and the test suites. Attachments included.